# Slow boot OS Lion on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

I have macbook pro 15.4 2011 (Core i7, 4gb, 500HDD), Lion is running on it. The annoying thing is that the boot time is too much, it takes roughly 70 to 120 seconds for machine to boot and display login screen :(

I have removed all programs from Login items.

Any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem with my Macbook Pro (early 2015). I had a long time a perfect working triple boot setup with refind. But lately the Boot process is some kind of weird. It takes very long time until the bootloader shows up (the 70 to 120 seconds from the question). It makes no difference if it is with refind or the original mac bootloader. The symptoms are as follows: 1. I have to wait the 70 to 120 seconds until refind or the macbook bootloader shows up
2. Then it is very slow in the boot menu, if the bootloader offers options. The same goes for the recovery boot from internet. It is n

Answer (score 2):

You could press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (verbose boot) at startup. No Apple logo will appear, but the screen will turn black and print a lot of text as it boots up. (As soon as the OS has booted, it will go into graphics mode, don't worry.)

Whenever an action takes very long and it prints some message (either in progress or afterwards), write it down or take a photo of the screen. You can then google for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try a **[PRAM Reset](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379)**

1. Restart the computer.
2. Press and hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys. You must press this key combination before the gray screen appears.
3. Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.